# How to save the Gap value from the Engine Log into a variable in Cplex

Tags: mathematical-optimization, cplex

I am solving an NP-Hard problem using IBM-Ilog-Cplex, and I am interrupting the solution process after one hour of run-time to evaluate how close Cplex got to the optimal solution (i.e. to evaluate the solution gap).  As part of my analysis, I need to take the last value for the "Gap" reported in the Engine Log and save it into a variable so that I can use such variable to export the gap value to excel as part of my results.

I have searched the manual and several resources and I have not found a way of doing this other than manually cutting and pasting the gap value; If what I am asking is not possible, is there a way to extract the last values for  the "Best Integer" and the "Best Bound" from the engine log so I can calculate the "Gap" ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Ram,  Thank you for your feedback; it helped me understand better how CPLEX deals with the gap; however, I was unsuccessful at obtaining  such value in an easy/direct way.  I have been researching the topic, and all the examples I have seen on the forums use external code (Java or C++) to call CPLEX and obtain the gap - it seems like that's the way to go.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how you call CPLEX.
You can query the best bound, the best objective value and the relative gap e.g. in the callable library interface, I do it like this:

```
            optstatus = CPXmipopt (env, lp);
            mipstatus = CPXgetstat (env, lp);
            if (!optstatus && !DDSIP_Error(optstatus) && !DDSIP_Infeasible (mipstatus))
            {
                if (CPXgetmiprelgap(env, lp, &mipgap))
                {
                    fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: Query of CPLEX mip gap from 1st optimization failed (LowerBound) \n");
                    fprintf (stderr, "       CPXgetstat returned: %d\n",mipstatus);
                    mipgap = 1.e+30;
                }
                if (param->cpxscr || param->outlev > 10)
                {
                    j = CPXgetnodecnt (env,lp);
                    printf ("      LB: after 1st optimization: mipgap %% %-12lg %5d nodes  (%6.2fs)\n",mipgap*100.0,j,time_lap-time_start);
                    if (param->outlev)
                        fprintf (moreoutfile,"      LB: after 1st optimization: mipgap %% %-12lg %5d nodes  (%6.2fs)\n",mipgap*100.0,j,time_lap-time_start);
                }
```

In the C++-interface there are similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you solving an IP or a MIP. There are a couple of parameters that CPLEX allows you to set:

- MIPInterval and
- MIPDisplay

These will show up in the **Node Log** file that gets generated. This [help page](http://www-eio.upc.es/lceio/manuals/cplex-11/html/usrcplex/solveMIP20.html) is quite useful. Hope that helps you move forward.